# Reorder factor levels within group

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to reorder the levels of a factor in one column, but within groups defined by a grouping column.

Simple example data set:

```
df <- structure(list(a_factor = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("group1", "group2"), class = "factor"), 
value = 1:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

> df
  a_factor  group value
1        a group1     1
2        b group1     2
3        c group1     3
4        d group2     4
5        e group2     5
6        f group2     6
```

More precisely, how do I reorder the factor levels, e.g. descending by `value` where `df$group == "group1"`, but ascending by `value` where `df$group == "group2"`, preferably in dplyr?

An expected output might be:

```
> df
  a_factor  group value
1        c group1     3
2        b group1     2
3        a group1     1
4        d group2     4
5        e group2     5
6        f group2     6
```

Although, the question is more generally about how to tackle this in dplyr.

Comment: Do you neeed `df %>% arrange(group, desc(value))`

Comment: No, I need more control about how to arrange the values (or ideally factor levels) within the different groups. So for group == group1, I might want to keep the order ascending, but descending for group == group2 (or the other way around, just as an example)

Comment: Can you please update the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reorder the factor levels you can use `forcats` (part of the `tidyverse`), and do something like this...

```
library(forcats)
df2 <- df %>% mutate(a_factor = fct_reorder(a_factor,
                                            value*(-1 + 2 * (group=="group1"))))

levels(df2$a_factor)
[1] "f" "e" "d" "a" "b" "c"
```

This does not rearrange the dataframe itself...

```
df2
  a_factor  group value
1        a group1     1
2        b group1     2
3        c group1     3
4        d group2     4
5        e group2     5
6        f group2     6
```

Comment: This is closer to the solution I was hoping for, since it is reordering the factor levels. Can you explain what the code in `fct_reorder` does, specifically the `value*(-1 + 2 * ` bit?

Comment: @Joris The `-1+2*(group=="group1")` evaluates as `-1` if `group` is not `group1`, and `+1` if it is `group1`. So the levels are reordered according to the sort of the sequence `1,2,3,-4,-5,-6`, i.e. `-6,-5,-4,1,2,3`.  I've just spotted that you actually want them the other way round, so just replace `group1` by `group2` in the formula. Sorry about that!

Comment: Oh, it's just an example anyways, both are fine. Many thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

We can negate based on group value then order:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(case_when(
    group == "group1" ~ -value,
    group == "group2" ~ value))

#   a_factor  group value
# 1        c group1     3
# 2        b group1     2
# 3        a group1     1
# 4        d group2     4
# 5        e group2     5
# 6        f group2     6
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a base R solution.

```
sp <- split(df$value, df$group)
sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i) sort(sp[[i]], decreasing = i == 1))
df$a_factor <- factor(df$a_factor, levels = df$a_factor[unlist(sp)])

df$a_factor
#[1] a b c d e f
#Levels: c b a d e f

df[order(df$a_factor), ]
#  a_factor  group value
#3        c group1     3
#2        b group1     2
#1        a group1     1
#4        d group2     4
#5        e group2     5
#6        f group2     6
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to do a `group_split` and pass a `list` of logical values corresponding to how the `arrange` needs to be executed

```
library(tidyverse)   
df %>% 
    group_split(group) %>%
    map2_df(., list(FALSE, TRUE), ~ if(.y) .x %>%
       arrange(value) else  .x %>% arrange(desc(value)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  a_factor group  value
#  <fct>    <fct>  <int>
#1 c        group1     3
#2 b        group1     2
#3 a        group1     1
#4 d        group2     4
#5 e        group2     5
#6 f        group2     6
```